# map "table per class hierarchy" superclass having subclasses mapping sub classes of another "table per class hierarchy"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

Sorry for long title..

I have the following error when querying a `TableColumn` entity:

> Could not set field value
>   [org.comp.domain.data.ConstantParameterType@18c81fe5] value by
>   reflection : [class org.comp.data.AnalogParameter.analogParameterType]
>   setter of org.comp.data.AnalogParameter.analogParameterType; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set
>   field value [org.comp.data.ConstantParameterType@18c81fe5] value by
>   reflection : [class
>   org.comp.domain.data.AnalogParameter.analogParameterType] setter of
>   org.comp.domain.data.AnalogParameter.analogParameterType

My model contains two distincts 'single table per class' hierarchies having `Parameter` and `ParameterType` as superclasses. Each subclasse of `Parameter` hierarchy is mapped with a subclass of `ParameterType` hierarchy through `@ManyToOne` associations.
Here is an extract of my model with involved entities (unrelated fields ommitted):

```
// `Parameter` Single Table Per Class hierarchy

@Entity
@Table(name="parameters")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "category", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)

@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
public abstract class Parameter {

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="analog")
public class AnalogParameter extends Parameter {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parameter_type_id")
    private AnalogParameterType analogParameterType;

    public AnalogParameterType getAnalogParameterType() {
        return analogParameterType;
    }

    public void setAnalogParameterType(AnalogParameterType analogParameterType) {
        this.analogParameterType = analogParameterType;
    }


}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="constant")
public class ConstantParameter extends Parameter {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parameter_type_id")
    private ConstantParameterType constantParameterType;

    public ConstantParameterType getConstantParameterType() {
        return constantParameterType;
    }

    public void setConstantParameterType(ConstantParameterType constantParameterType) {
        this.constantParameterType = constantParameterType;
    }

}

// `ParameterType` Single Table Per Class hierarchy

@Entity
@Table(name="parameters_types")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "category", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)

@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
public abstract class ParameterType { }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="analog")
public class AnalogParameterType extends ParameterType { }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="constant")
public class ConstantParameterType extends ParameterType {

}
```

Here is the TableColumn which is mapped with Parameter superclass through a @ManyToOne association:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tables_columns")
public class TableColumn {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parameter_id")
    private Parameter parameter;

    public Parameter getParameter() {
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

And here is the generated SQL when querying A TableColumn Entity:

> select tablecolum0_.id as id1_12_0_, tablecolum0_.created_at as
>   created_2_12_0_, tablecolum0_.is_optional as is_optio3_12_0_,
>   tablecolum0_.parameter_id as paramete6_12_0_, tablecolum0_.position as
>   position4_12_0_, tablecolum0_.updated_at as updated_5_12_0_,
>   parameter1_.id as id2_8_1_, parameter1_.category as category1_8_1_,
>   parameter1_.created_at as created_3_8_1_, parameter1_.device_id as
>   device_14_8_1_, parameter1_.effective_date as effectiv4_8_1_,
>   parameter1_.expiry_date as expiry_d5_8_1_, parameter1_.fqn as
>   fqn6_8_1_, parameter1_.height_from_the_ground as height_f7_8_1_,
>   parameter1_.label as label8_8_1_, parameter1_.name as name9_8_1_,
>   parameter1_.resolution_label as resolut10_8_1_, parameter1_.updated_at
>   as updated11_8_1_, parameter1_.parameter_type_id as paramet15_8_1_,
>   parameter1_.data_validity_period as data_va12_8_1_,
>   parameter1_.resolution as resolut13_8_1_, device2_.id as id1_1_2_,
>   device2_.created_at as created_2_1_2_, device2_.device_type_id as
>   device_t8_1_2_, device2_.fqn as fqn3_1_2_, device2_.label as
>   label4_1_2_, device2_.name as name5_1_2_, device2_.notes as
>   notes6_1_2_, device2_.parent_device_id as parent_d9_1_2_,
>   device2_.plant_id as plant_i10_1_2_, device2_.updated_at as
>   updated_7_1_2_, constantpa3_.id as id2_9_3_, constantpa3_.created_at
>   as created_3_9_3_, constantpa3_.description as descript4_9_3_,
>   constantpa3_.is_signed as is_signe5_9_3_, constantpa3_.label as
>   label6_9_3_, constantpa3_.name as name7_9_3_, constantpa3_.updated_at
>   as updated_8_9_3_ from tables_columns tablecolum0_ left outer join
>   parameters parameter1_ on tablecolum0_.parameter_id=parameter1_.id
>   left outer join devices device2_ on parameter1_.device_id=device2_.id
>   left outer join parameters_types constantpa3_ on
>   parameter1_.parameter_type_id=constantpa3_.id where tablecolum0_.id=1

I'm using Hibernate 5.0.11 with MySQL in a Spring Boot 1.4.1 / Data Rest project

**EDIT**

I tried in a vanilla Maven/Hibernate project using the same database. I have the same error. If i query `Parameter` objects directly, it's OK, but i get the error if i query `TableColumn`:

```
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa" );
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    // The following works
    List<Parameter> ps = entityManager.createQuery("from Parameter", Parameter.class).getResultList();
    for (Parameter p: ps) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }

    // But if i replace with following, i get the same error as reported
    // in the beginning of this question
    List<TableColumn> tcs = entityManager.createQuery("from TableColumn", TableColumn.class).getResultList();
    for (TableColumn tc: tcs) {
        System.out.println(tc);
    }


    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
```

Comment: looking at your mapping I see no @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)

Comment: unfortunatelly it does not fix the issue. As stated on the [JPA @inheritance association at Hibernate javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Inheritance.html), it is the default type when not specified

Comment: thanks for the information. I did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Your `category` is of `size=7`, but you are setting a value of `8 characters` i.e, `constant`

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="category", length=7)//change to more than 7
```

Because, `@DiscriminatorValue(value="constant")//here the length is 8`

You can use the below code for Discriminator column:

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "category", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)//no need of length attribute
```

**2)** verify that for the property `private AnalogParameterType analogParameterType;` you have below setter and getter methods.

```
//setter    
public void setAnalogParameterType(AnalogParameterType analogParameterType) {
    this.analogParameterType = analogParameterType;
}
//getter
public AnalogParameterType getAnalogParameterType() {
    return analogParameterType;
}
```

**3)** Instead of
`@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="parameter_type_id")`

use `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` on **getters**.
**For example:**

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public AnalogParameterType getAnalogParameterType() {
    return analogParameterType;
}
```

Comment: It's a good catch, but it does not resolve my issue unfortunatelly. I edited the question by replacing @DiscriminatorColumn with your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: The accessors are there. I've added them on the question (through copy paste from real code)

Comment: about 3): I tried and gave a >com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'parameter0_.constantParameterType_id' in 'field list'

Comment: (can't edit my previous post ?) ... It searches for a non existent association column..

Answer (score 0):

So i solved my issue by mapping the two superclasses `Parameter` and `ParameterType` with insertable/updatable=false:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parameters")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "category", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) 
public abstract class Parameter {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parameter_type_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private ParameterType parameterType;

}
```

It appears that enforcing the association at the superclass level does the  trick. I don't know if it is a pure side effect or a design need. I have not found any resources on the subject.